# Can I initialize the broken view mode?

Tags: 8

In a bundle of content types, I placed fields on many vertical tabs of the field group.
In order to switch display / non-display of the field, I moved and saved it without going well for each tab.
Movement of many fields and field groups at one time was not very easy.
t was saved with tab items and fields that do not belong to parent tab.
After that, even when tabs and fields were moved and saved, there was no change.

I think that the View mode is broken.
I also copied the broken view mode to default.
Therefore, all the view modes are deleted, the newly created view mode is copied from the broken default and remains broken.

Is there a way to restore the default view mode for a particular bundle?

Environment:
Drupal 8.5.6,
Field group module 8.x-3.0-beta1,
Display Suite 8.x-3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the config and open the view mode in a text editor or run this drush command from the command line:

```
drush cedit core.entity_view_display.node.[content-type].default
```

Then remove the field settings you think could break your view mode and import the config again or exit/save if you used the drush command.

Comment: For additional explanation, I can not save the sort of the field and furthermore the label and format settings are not saved.
I want to edit with core.entity_view_display.node.[content-type].default.yml, but I can not understand it because there are too many setting config items.
Is there a configuration to display only the body field?
Is this work complete only by editing the yaml file without affecting the database?

Comment: You can create such an example by configuring a new display mode with only a body field and open this yaml file.

Comment: I see.
I will create a new bundle, check the yaml file and see.
Thanks.

Comment: please tell me.
What does the dependencies: config: section of the yaml file mean?
Where is the configuration manual?

Comment: I could not understand the meaning of the settings in the Config.yml file. I was able to repeat the validity and invalidity of the field of the display, and I was able to bring it back to the state close to the default with good luck. Although it could not be solved by the method taught, I will make it resolve.